# Select and sum multiple columns for statistic purposes with Laravel query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have one table `scores` where I have saving users scores. It's looks like this

```
table `scores`

id | points | user_id
 1     5          1
 2     2          1
 3     4          1
 4     1          3
 5     10         2
```

I want to select each user, sum his points and show as a ranking. The result from above should be

```
user_id | points
  1         11
  2         10
  3         1
```

The query with which I came up is

```
$sumPoints = Scores::select( \DB::raw("sum(points) as numberOfPoints"), \DB::raw("count(id) as numberId"))->groupBy("user_id")->first();
```

The problem is in `->first()` because it's return only one result.. it is working as must. If I try to use `->get()` instead I've got `Undefined property` error. How should I use this?

The query which is working in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT count(id) as numberId, sum(points) as numberOfPoints FROM `points` GROUP BY `user_id`
```

Comment: What will you try to print after adding `->get()`?

Comment: I've tried `dd($sumPoints->numberOfPoints)` just to see if is working

Comment: If you are using `get()` which will return a collection, hence you would need to loop through `$sumPoints` to access the properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$sumPoints = Scores::select( \DB::raw("sum(points) as numberOfPoints"), \DB::raw("count(id) as numberId"))->groupBy("user_id")->get();
foreach($sumPoints as $point){
      dd($point); //OR dd($point->numberOfPoints)
}
```

Comment: Because here get() give multiple result user wise